# Custom EDID for specfic physical monitor, not output

Tags: xorg, nvidia, display, xrandr, edid

I have a setup where I connect to two different displays depending on where I am. I would like to use a mode which one of the monitors doesn't allow, but that won't be loaded when any other display is connected.

To be more concrete, the I would like to overclock the external display at home to 120hz, but not overclock a different display at work that I connect to the same HDMI port. Is this possible using nvidia? I can't seem to be able to override EDID with xrandr, at the same time using the EDID settings by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if using nvidia you can refer to monitors by their EDID here is an example from my 99-nvidia.conf ([Reference I used here](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/396.51/README/displaydevicenames.html))

```
Section "Module"
    Load "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24

    #this is the important part!!!
    Option         "CustomEDID" "DPY-EDID-d2ee947f-cde6-694c-4099-2f7aa520eb75: /home/myName/Documents/monitors/edid-120.bin"


    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver  "nvidia"
    BusID   "PCI:1:0:0"
    #Option  "DPI" "96 x 96"    #adjust this value as needed to fix scaling
    Option  "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option  "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

The EDID override feature of the `nvidia` driver seems to require specifying the monitor whose EDID should be overridden by the output ID.

You may have to somehow detect "where you are" before starting the X server, and then either switch your `xorg.conf` file to one of two prepared alternatives, or add/remove a `xorg.conf.d` snippet accordingly.

See this webpage for ideas: https://kodi.wiki/view/Creating_and_using_edid.bin_via_xorg.conf

You might be able to use the `read-edid` and `edid-decode` packages to read the actual EDID before the X server starts up, decode it to identify the display, then switch the X configuration file accordingly, then proceed with the X server start-up. Or you might use network parameters or something else you can readily detect before X start-up to determine which configuration should be used.

Since you haven't specified which Linux distribution you're using, I cannot suggest an exact procedure for inserting your custom script into the proper place in the system start-up sequence, but it is definitely possible to do it.

Comment: The distro is Manjaro with xfce in this case. I think I'm good with the procedure just need to find out if the xfce monitors.xml will interfere. Thank you :)